# Android - Get auto cropped bitmap using OpenCV rectangle detection

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, bitmap

I am using OPENCV to detect bank check while camera starts  preview and its working fine.
i am getting bitmap value from Mat data whenever rectangle is detected , but i want to have only document image not entire frame bitmap(portion which is detected in rectangle form), Kindly guide me mates.

Thanks in Advance and apologies if some format mistake.

Refrence: https://github.com/iyotetsuya/RectangleDetection

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    CameraPreview cameraPreview = (CameraPreview) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    cameraPreview.setCallback((data, camera) -> {
    CameraData cameraData = new CameraData();
    cameraData.data = data;
    cameraData.camera = camera;
    subject.onNext(cameraData);
    });
    cameraPreview.setOnClickListener(v -> cameraPreview.focus());
    DrawView drawView = (DrawView) findViewById(R.id.draw_layout);
    subject.concatMap(cameraData ->
    OpenCVHelper.getRgbMat(new MatData(), cameraData.data, cameraData.camera))
    .concatMap(matData -> OpenCVHelper.resize(matData, 400, 400))
    .map(matData -> {
    matData.resizeRatio = (float) matData.oriMat.height() / matData.resizeMat.height();
    matData.cameraRatio = (float) cameraPreview.getHeight() / matData.oriMat.height();
    return matData;
    })
    .concatMap(this::detectRect)
    .compose(mainAsync())
    .subscribe(matData -> {
    if (drawView != null) {
    if (matData.cameraPath != null) {
    drawView.setPath(matData.cameraPath);
    mat = matData.oriMat;
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mat.width(), mat.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    } else {
    drawView.setPath(null);
    }
    drawView.invalidate();
    }
    });
    }
```