# OpenCV Android - Unable to Set Detected Image to Bitmap

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, bitmap

I'm attempting to implement OpenCV for Android to detect a rectangle then set the detected image to a bitmap.

I'm able to detect a rectangle, then apply that to a bitmap - but it applies the entire screen, instead of the detected image.

Where might I have gone wrong in this implementation?

P.S.

If you know the answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43804958/android-get-auto-cropped-bitmap-using-opencv-rectangle-detection) person is looking to do the same.

Any suggestions are appreciated. 
[image]

### Source:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    static {
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.v(TAG, "init OpenCV");
        }
    }

    private PublishSubject<CameraData> subject = PublishSubject.create();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        CameraPreview cameraPreview = (CameraPreview) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        cameraPreview.setCallback((data, camera) -> {
            CameraData cameraData = new CameraData();
            cameraData.data = data;
            cameraData.camera = camera;
            subject.onNext(cameraData);
        });
        cameraPreview.setOnClickListener(v -> cameraPreview.focus());
        DrawView drawView = (DrawView) findViewById(R.id.draw_layout);
        subject.concatMap(cameraData ->
                OpenCVHelper.getRgbMat(new MatData(), cameraData.data, cameraData.camera))
                .concatMap(matData -> OpenCVHelper.resize(matData, 400, 400))
                .map(matData -> {
                    matData.resizeRatio = (float) matData.oriMat.height() / matData.resizeMat.height();
                    matData.cameraRatio = (float) cameraPreview.getHeight() / matData.oriMat.height();
                    return matData;
                })
                .concatMap(this::detectRect)
                .compose(mainAsync())
                .subscribe(matData -> {
                    if (drawView != null) {
                        if (matData.cameraPath != null) {
                            drawView.setPath(matData.cameraPath);

                            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(matData.oriMat.width(), matData.oriMat.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                            Utils.matToBitmap(matData.oriMat, bitmap);
                            ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                            iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        } else {
                            drawView.setPath(null);
                        }
                        drawView.invalidate();
                    }
                });
    }

    private Observable<MatData> detectRect(MatData mataData) {
        return Observable.just(mataData)
                .concatMap(OpenCVHelper::getMonochromeMat)
                .concatMap(OpenCVHelper::getContoursMat)
                .concatMap(OpenCVHelper::getPath);
    }

    private static <T> Observable.Transformer<T, T> mainAsync() {
        return obs -> obs.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you are **cropping** the detected rectangle from the original mat. I just see that you are putting the original mat to the imageView